# my gridcell overlap my imageview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to cover one cell of grid view with static imageview but when i add imageview, it appears below the cell but i want it to be above the cell so that cell image is covered by static imageview which can move when cell moves. In my code my imageview is going blow the cell but i want one image which is fixed always comes just top of the gridcell. When i move cell my imageview doesn't move

```
DWExampleGridViewController.h
#import "DWGridController.h"

@interface DWExampleGridViewController : DWGridViewController
{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv;
@end


    DWExampleGridViewController.m


    #import "DWExampleGridViewController.h"
    #import "DWExampleGridViewCell.h"
    #import "DWExampleGridViewController.h"
    #import "DWGridViewController.h"
    @interface DWExampleGridViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation DWExampleGridViewController
    @synthesize iv;
    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {

            for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
                {

                        DWExampleGridViewCell *cell = [[DWExampleGridViewCell alloc] init];
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d.jpeg",row,col]];

                        iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                        [iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
                     iv.clipsToBounds = YES;

                        [iv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
                        //[cell addSubview:iv];
                    //[self.view insertSubview:iv atIndex:0];

                        [cell insertSubview:iv atIndex:0];

                        [cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[iv]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(iv)]];
                        [cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[iv]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(iv)]];

                        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                        [dict setObject:cell forKey:@"Cell"];
                        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] forKey:@"Row"];
                        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:col] forKey:@"Column"];


                        if(image)
                            [dict setObject:image forKey:@"Image"];
                        [self.cells addObject:dict];
                }
            }


        }
         [self image];

        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {


    }
    -(void)image
    {
        DWExampleGridViewCell *cell = [[DWExampleGridViewCell alloc] init];
        UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        v.frame=CGRectMake(108,155, 105, 160);
        v.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpeg"];
        [v setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        v.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //DWExampleGridViewController *grid = [[DWExampleGridViewController alloc]init];
        //[self.view insertSubview:v aboveSubview:grid.iv];
        //[self.view insertSubview:v atIndex:2];
        //[cell insertSubview:v atIndex:1];
        //[cell insertSubview:v aboveSubview:iv];
        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] insertSubview:v aboveSubview:cell];
         [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.gridView];

    }



    #pragma mark - GridView datasource
    -(NSInteger)numberOfColumnsInGridView:(DWGridView *)gridView
    {
        return 8;
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInGridView:(DWGridView *)gridView
    {
        return 8;
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfVisibleRowsInGridView:(DWGridView *)gridView
    {
        return 3;
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfVisibleColumnsInGridView:(DWGridView *)gridView
    {
        return 3;
    }


    #pragma mark - GridView delegate
    -(void)gridView:(DWGridView *)gridView didSelectCell:(DWGridViewCell *)cell atPosition:(DWPosition)position
    {
        NSDictionary *cellDictionary = [self cellDictionaryAtPosition:position];
        UIImage *image = [cellDictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        UIViewController *contr = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [contr.view addSubview:button];

        [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
        [contr.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[button]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];

        [self presentViewController:contr animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)buttonTapped
    {

        [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a custom cell
2. Add the static image to the cells contentView by using `addSubview:`
3. Whenever you want the image to be on top call `[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:imageView]`

If this doesn't help - post a screenshot of what's wrong and how you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make view having same properties as cell.
2. add that view on keywindow on required position.
3. Never forgot of [view removeFromSuperview] on viewWillDisappear delegate.